# リモートでのタスクスケジュール登録コマンドがアクセス拒否される

Tags: windows-10

リモートPCへタスクスケジュール登録を行う下記のようなバッチファイルを管理者権限で実行したところ、「アクセスが拒否されました」のエラーが出力されてしまいます。

```
@echo off
schtasks /Create ^
/S 192.168.XX.XXX ^
/U USER ^
/P PASS ^
/tn notepad ^
/tr "'\\192.168.XX.XXX\共有\sample.txt'" ^
/sc MONTHLY ^
/sd 2020/07/01 ^
/d 1 ^
/st 03:23 ^
/ru USER ^
/rp PASS ^
/rl highest 


echo.
echo [Complete]
echo.
echo Enter any key
pause > nul
exit
```

このエラーが出力されてしまう原因・解決策を教えていただきたいです。
尚、リモートへpingが通ることは確認済みです。

環境はローカル・リモートともにwindows10 proです。
宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: これかもしれませんね。[schtasks](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/schtasks) **ローカルおよびリモート コンピューターが同じドメインまたはローカル コンピューターがリモート コンピューターのドメインが信頼しているドメインにするときにのみ操作します。 それ以外の場合、リモート コンピューターは、指定したユーザー アカウントを認証できないし、アカウントが Administrators グループのメンバーであることを確認できません。**